# How to auto enable the Horizontal and Vertical scroll-bar in pyqt5 using python

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I'm new to PyQt5 and Python, My question is how to enable the Horizontal scroll-bar if user enter more data in single line of the input box?

Currently it Input box enabling vertical scroll-bar if you enter more data.

can any one help me out how to enable both horizontal and Vertical scroll-bar if user enter more data?

Current Python Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.height = 480
        self.width = 640
        self.top = 10
        self.left = 10
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(800, 600))
        self.setWindowTitle("My Windows")

        # .... other Code here

        # Edit Box
        input_et_box = QFrame(self)
        input_et_box.resize(300, 450)
        input_et_box.move(50, 80)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(input_et_box)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        # If we enter more data in Edit Box it will automatically enabled Vertical Scroll bar but Horizontal Scroll bar is not enabling automatically
        # bar is not enabling

    def printHello(self):
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    layout = QGridLayout()
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Snapshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please any one have a look on this , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)`